# iOS9 sendSynchronousRequest deprecated

Tags: ios, swift

> Warning:'sendSynchronousRequest(_:returningResponse:)' was deprecated
>   in iOS 9.0: Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]
>   (see NSURLSession)

```
urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
```

Any idea on how to get rid of this warning?  I just upgraded from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2

UPDATE: Fonix is marked as my best answer.   If your trying to add a try statement, I modified his answer as followed:

```
urlData = try NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest(<#request: NSURLRequest#>, completionHandler: <#((NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void)?##(NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void#>)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `NSURLSession` instead like below,

For Objective-C

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]
          completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                              NSURLResponse *response,
                              NSError *error) {
            // handle response

  }] resume];
```

For Swift,

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "YOUR URL"))
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var params = ["username":"username", "password":"password"] as Dictionary<String, String>

var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    println("Response: \(response)")})

task.resume()
```

Comment: But are the semantics the same?  In particular, `sendSynchronousRequest` will block the calling thread until the responses is received, which is sometimes exactly what you want.  According to the reference docs, `resume` will execute the request asynchronously, meaning it's not an exact replacement of the deprecated functionality.

Comment: No that a `queue` argument is missing.

Comment: This is not a correct answer, because it is not synchronous.

Answer (score 26):

I wrote the following solution for the cases when you actually need for synchronous request which blocks the current thread execution. I use this code for migration from `NSURLConnection` to `NSURLSession` in the complex solution where it was **quite a hassle** to just change to async approach. With this solution the migration is just method name replacement.

*NOTE: If you have a simple case, please use the accepted answer instead.*

```
- (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
{

    NSError __block *err = NULL;
    NSData __block *data;
    BOOL __block reqProcessed = false;
    NSURLResponse __block *resp;

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable _data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable _response, NSError * _Nullable _error) {
        resp = _response;
        err = _error;
        data = _data;
        reqProcessed = true;
    }] resume];

    while (!reqProcessed) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.02];
    }
    if (response != nil)
        *response = resp;
    if (error != nil)
        *error = err;
    return data;
}
```

Usage (simple replace `NSURLConnection` to this method):

```
//NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&resp error:&err];
NSData *data = [self sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&resp error:&err];
```

Comment: WARNING! This has caused some widespread hanging/crashing in our app. Our users started receiving the infamous 'wakeups' logs. It was happening when they had poor networking conditions. I have not modified the method, we reverted to the deprecated method for now. I might suggest sleepForTimeInternal to 20ms at the least. In the event the network request is timing out, 0 will cause excessive wakeups, and utilize 100% CPU when requests take too long to respond.

Comment: Adding a timeout to the URL request can help with that issue.

`[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"URL"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0]`

Answer (score 25):

If you need to block the current thread (like Mike Keskinov's answer), best to use gdc semaphore instead of doing a [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0].  e.g.

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]
          completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                              NSURLResponse *response,
                              NSError *error) {
            // handle response
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

  }] resume];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

and Swift (tested on 5.0):

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:0)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: serverUrl) { (httpData, response, error) in
    // handle response
    semaphore.signal()
}.resume()

semaphore.wait()
```

Comment: By 1001 - you mean HTTP timeouts?  Which I doubt is related to the above code - unless your web server is running in the same thread ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I have modified the code of Nilesh Patel a little bit, so you can use the old call, just by changing class name.

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error {
__block NSData *blockData = nil;
@try {

        __block NSURLResponse *blockResponse = nil;
        __block NSError *blockError = nil;

        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable subData, NSURLResponse * _Nullable subResponse, NSError * _Nullable subError) {

            blockData = subData;
            blockError = subError;
            blockResponse = subResponse;

            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }] resume];

        dispatch_group_wait(group,  DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        *error = blockError;
        *response = blockResponse;

    } @catch (NSException *exception) {

        NSLog(@"%@", exception.description);
    } @finally {
        return blockData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 / Xcode 9**

If you really want the request to be synchronous like in the deprecated semantics, you can block the main thread with an empty loop on a condition set true by the completion handler:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "YOUR_URL")!)
let session = URLSession.shared
var gotResp = false

let task = session.dataTask(with: request,
            completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
                // do my thing...
                gotResp = true
            })
task.resume()

// block thread until completion handler is called
while !gotResp {
    // wait
}

print("Got response in main thread")
...
```

**EDIT:** or if you prefer to use semaphores like in the Obj-C Nick H247 answer:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "YOUR_URL")!)
let session = URLSession.shared
let ds = DispatchSemaphore( value: 0 )    
let task = session.dataTask(with: request,
            completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
                // do my thing..., then unblock main thread
                ds.signal()
            })
task.resume()

// block thread until semaphore is signaled
ds.wait()

print("Got response in main thread")
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete version of mine with  dispatch_semaphore_t and return response and error without block assign warning .  Thank @Nick H247 and @Mike Keskinov.

```
- (NSData*)sendSynchronousRequest:NSURLRequest *urlRequest
                returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)outResponse
                            error:(NSError **)outError
{

    NSError __block *err = NULL;
    NSData __block *data;
    BOOL __block reqProcessed = false;
    NSURLResponse __block *resp;

//    data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:response error:error];

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    NSURLSession *session = _session;
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
            completionHandler:^(NSData *_data,
                                NSURLResponse *_response,
                                NSError *_error) {
                // handle response
                data = _data;
                resp = _response;
                err = _error;

                reqProcessed = true;

                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

            }] resume];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    if (reqProcessed) {
        if(outResponse != NULL) {
            *outResponse = resp;
        }

        if (outError != NULL) {
            *outError = err;
        }

    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: How about in this code?  NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    if (jsonData == nil) {
        [self showSimpleAlert:@"ネットワークに接続できませんでした"];
        return;
    }
    NSError *error = nil;

Answer (score 1):

you can hide that warning in your project by using following code write your method between input directives and your warning goes away.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push 
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
- (void)yourMethodToCallNSURLConnection {
//use deprecated stuff
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: this is very good to know, thanks!  However, I like to keep my classes up to date just in case future updates removes functionality of deprecated classes

Comment: @DevTonio deprecated classes will not be out of order immediately, it takes long time. Though its good to upgrade your code. Thanks for appreciation.

Comment: This is an important part of keeping code up-to-date and having refactoring sessions in your projects. I would never accept this for a project with a chance that suddenly one day all my users contact me that thousands of apps start crashing. Every notice should be treated the same as an error and be dealt with now, not later.