# Convert my code to iOS 9

Tags: ios9, xcode7

It gives me alert in:

```
urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
```

also in the UIAlertView

could some one help me to convert it to iOS 9 :

This is the images for the alert

[image]

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    let username:NSString = txtUsername.text!
    let password:NSString = txtPassword.text!

    if ( username.isEqualToString("") || password.isEqualToString("") ) {

        let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
        alertView.message = "Please enter Username and Password"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
    } else {

        do {
            let post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

            NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"https://dipinkrishna.com/jsonlogin2.php")!

            let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

            let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

            let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = postData
            request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


            var reponseError: NSError?
            var response: NSURLResponse?

            var urlData: NSData?
            do {
                urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                reponseError = error
                urlData = nil
            }

            if ( urlData != nil ) {
                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

                NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

                if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
                {
                    let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

                    //var error: NSError?

                    let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary


                    let success:NSInteger = jsonData.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

                    //[jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

                    NSLog("Success: %ld", success);

                    if(success == 1)
                    {
                        NSLog("Login SUCCESS");

                        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                        prefs.setObject(username, forKey: "USERNAME")
                        prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                        prefs.synchronize()

                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        var error_msg:NSString

                        if jsonData["error_message"] as? NSString != nil {
                            error_msg = jsonData["error_message"] as! NSString
                        } else {
                            error_msg = "Unknown Error"
                        }
                        let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                        alertView.message = error_msg as String
                        alertView.delegate = self
                        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertView.show()

                    }

                } else {
                    let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                    alertView.message = "Connection Failed"
                    alertView.delegate = self
                    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    alertView.show()
                }
            } else {
                let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
                alertView.message = "Connection Failure"
                if let error = reponseError {
                    alertView.message = (error.localizedDescription)
                }
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()
            }
        } catch {
            let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Server Error"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The replacing of `UIAlertView` with `UIAlertController` and replacing of `NSURLConnection` with `NSURLSession` have been asked and answered many times here. Before asking this, did you search Stack Overflow for existing questions on these topics?

Comment: I find the solution for the UIAlertView, but i still have errors with "var reponseError: NSError?
            var response: NSURLResponse?

            var urlData: NSData?
            do {
                urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                reponseError = error
                urlData = nil
            }"

Comment: To retire `NSURLConnection`, see [the accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32649027/1271826). Just search Stack Overflow for "[ios] [swift] sendsynchronousrequest" and you'll find lots of examples.  Or, better, google "swift NSURLSession tutorial" or things like that to find good introductions to Swift nad `NSURLSession`.